# openAL won't play a second song

Tags: ios, audio, openal, audio-player

I've been working on making an app that plays music from the user's music library using alsource, but I've run into a bug I can't seem to get around. After my first song finishes (or I stop it), I try to play a second one, and it leaves me in silence.

```
alGenSources(1, &source);
```

seems to be the first line where things go wrong. 
Here's how I clear the source and buffers when I'm done with the first song.

```
 alDeleteSources(1,&source); 
 alDeleteBuffers(1,buffers); 
 context=alcGetCurrentContext(); 
 device=alcGetContextsDevice(context); 
 alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL); 
 alcDestroyContext(context); 
 alcCloseDevice(device);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding the line

```
 source+=1
```

Solved everything